# Searching or a specific substring in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

This question is possibly a duplicate but any answers i find don't seem to work. I have a .txt file full of this layout:

artist - song, www.link.com

artist2 - song2, www.link2.com

This is my general purpose:

```
uinput = input("input here: ")

save = open("save.txt", "w+")
ncount = save.count("\n")

for i in range(0, ncount):
    t = save.readline()
    if uinput in t:
        print("Your string " uinput, " was found in" end = "")        
        print(t)
```

My intention is: If the userinput word was found in a line then print the entire line or the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension to read the file and get only the lines that contain the word, for example:

```
with open('save.txt', 'r') as f:
    uinput = input("input here: ")
    found = [line.rstrip() for line in f if uinput.lower() in line.lower()]
    if found:
        print('Found in these lines: ')
        print('\n'.join(found))
    else:
        print('Not found.')
```

If you want to print the link only, you can use:

```
found = [line.rstrip().split(',')[1] for line in f if uinput.lower() in line.lower()]
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You want to read the file, but you are opening the file in write mode. You should use `r`, not `w+`
2. The simplest way to iterate over a file is to have a `for` loop iterating directly over the file object
3. Not an error but a nitpick. You do not close your file. You can remedy this with `with.. as` context manager

---

```
uinput = input("input here: ")

with open("save.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if uinput in line:
            print('Match found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to fetch the lines containing  user input words.
use below code:

```
try:
    f = open("file/toyourpath/filename.txt", "r") 
    data_input = raw_input("Enter your listed song from file :");
    print data_input
    fetch_line = [line for line in f if data_input in line]
    print fetch_line
    f.close()
except ValueError, e:
    print e
```